# GCP - java11 springboot war file - entrypoint Issue

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, java-11

I am migrating my Spring Boot application (war) from Java 8 to Java 11
using app.yaml, and removed appengine-web.xml, all looks okay. But encountered below error when I build the war file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':myproject:appengineStage'.

> com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Cannot process application with runtime: java11. A custom entrypoint must be defined in your app.yaml for non-jar artifact: somepath\build\libs\myapp-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.war

How to resolve the issue? If entrypoint needs to be added, how can it be dynamic with the version number?

Comment: Hi @KrisSwat, could you please check this [WAR migration example in Java 11](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/war-packaging) and see if it helps. Also, can you provide your app.yaml in your post?

Comment: Thanks. I have seen that. Do I need to use AS-is?     server.createContext("/", (var t) -> {
      byte[] response = "Hello World from Google App Engine Java 11.".getBytes();
      t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length);
      try (OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody()) {
        os.write(response);
      }
    });

Comment: I am trying this approach - inside appengine -->   stage {
       artifact = "${buildDir}/libs/${project.name}.war"
 } and added  app.yaml ---> entrypoint: java -jar myappname.war
. Build is OK, but app is not starting.  [start] 2022/03/22 19:05:53.307556 Start program failed: failed to detect app after start: ForAppStart(): [aborted, context canceled. subject:"app/valid". Not sure how to fix

Comment: @CatherineO as you are in support, please can you give a full fledged spring boot gradle example which is java 11 for App Engine. without hardcoding - "Hello World from Google App Engine Java 11.".

Comment: I would recommend you to check out this guide [here](https://jagobapg.eu/p/2020/05/28/deploy-application-appengine-gradle-and-java-11/) as it has a step by step details on how you can deploy your spring boot gradle application.

Comment: This is different from the above google link. entrypoint: java -noverify -jar MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war , service: 'myapp'
env_variables:
  SERVER_PORT: 8080
  ELASTICSEARCH_HOST: 127.0.0.1
  ELASTICSEARCH_PORT: 9200
Why is 127.0.0.1 required and elasticsearch_port? Also service entry. I already have a java 8 app running, so cant take risk doing something I dont know